# How to directly map/expand object to stream?

Tags: java, dictionary, tree, java-8, reduce

Is it possible directly expand an object into a stream?

My current approach is:

```
private BigDecimal getNodeScore(Optional<Node> node) {
    return node.map(Node::getBranches)
               .orElseGet(Collections::emptySet)
               .stream()
               .filter(Branch::isValid)
               .flatMap(Branch::getLeafs)
               .map(Leaf::getScore)
               .reduce(BigDecimal::ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

It works quite well (yes, I know it's ugly.. for now) but is just hate using the orElseGet and steam to transition from Optional to Stream so I was wondering if there is any way to expand an Optional into a Stream?

What I need is something like:

```
private BigDecimal getNodeScore(Optional<Node> node) {
    return node.mapToStream(Node::getBranches)  // <-- Want something similar
               .filter(Branch::isValid)
               .flatMap(Branch::getLeafs)
               .map(Leaf::getScore)
               .reduce(BigDecimal::ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

I know I could always create a helper function and wrap the the first call with something like:

```
optionalToStream(node.map(Node::getBranches))
```

But was still wondering if there is any more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always convert an `Optional` to a `Stream` consisting of zero or one element using `optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)`. If the stream’s item can provide a `Stream`, you actually want to process, you can use `flatMap` to replace the stream’s item with the result stream of the evaluation or stay with an empty stream if the `Optional` was empty.

E.g.

```
Optional<Node> optional=Optional.empty();
optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)
   .map(Node::getBranches).flatMap(Collection::stream)
// follow-up operations
```

or

```
optional.map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty())
   .flatMap(node -> node.getBranches().stream())
// follow-up operations
```

but you can also fuse it into one operation in this special case

```
optional.map(node -> node.getBranches().stream()).orElse(Stream.empty())
// follow-up operations
```

(but I think it’s worth to know the general pattern before optimizing…)

Comment: Damn, Collection::stream was exactly what I needed, I just did node.map(Node::getBranches).map(Collection::stream).orElseGet(Stream::empty).filter(Branch::isValid)... and it worked perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: By the way, just did a rough test to see if ".map(node -> node.getbranches().stream())" would work faster than maping twice. Did 1000 runs on a tree roughly 10000 deep and 1000 wide and got only 1ms advantage on average. Though, I feel like the difference is too negligible to even care about that 1ms and If I'll decide to optimize the code at some point, I could always try parallelStream or even port this to C altogether. ;)

Comment: It had surprised me if there was a significant difference as all variants are basically doing the same and the different notations shouldn’t confuse the HotSpot optimizer. After all, you should use what you consider as more readable…

Answer (score 1):

> It works quite well (yes, I know it's ugly.. for now) but is just hate using the orElseGet and steam to transition from Optional to Stream

To be honest, I don't think your approach is ugly. You can still use `isPresent()` to test if the optional contains a value.

```
private BigDecimal getNodeScore(Optional<Node> node) {
    return node.isPresent() ? node.get()
                                  .getBranch()
                                  .stream()
                                  .filter(Branch::isValid)
                                  .flatMap(Branch::getLeafs)
                                  .map(Leaf::getScore)
                                  .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add) : BigDecimal.ZERO;
}
```

If you think it's worse, another workaround would be to provide a method in your Node class that returns a `Stream<Branch>` directly.

```
private BigDecimal getNodeScore(Optional<Node> node) {
    return node.map(Node::getBranchesStream)
               .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
               .filter(Branch::isValid)
               .flatMap(Branch::getLeafs)
               .map(Leaf::getScore)
               .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```

> Is it possible directly expand an object into a stream?

Yes there's `Stream.of` for this purpose, but you don't need it in your case since `getBranch` returns a `Set`, so you just have to call `stream()` on it to get the resulting stream.